# Ошибка 404 при POST-запросе

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Я делаю post-запрос на сервер и получаю ошибку 404:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот код обработки запроса:

```js
const { Router } = require('express');
const User = require('../models/User');
const config = require('config');
const cors = require('cors');

const router = Router();

const corsOptions = {
    origin: function (origin, callback) {
    if (config.get(CORS.whitelist).indexOf(origin) !== -1) {
        callback(null, true)
    } else {
        callback(new Error('Not allowed by CORS'))
        }
    }
}

router.post('/login', cors(corsOptions),
    async(req, res) => {
        try {
            const email = req.body.email;
            const candidate = await User.findOne({ email: email });
            if (isEmpty(email)) {
                console.log(3)
                return res.status(400).json({
                    msg: 'Некоректные данные при регистрации'
                });
            }

            if (candidate) {
                return res.status(400).json({
                    msg: 'Такой email уже зарегестрирован'
                });
            }

            const user = new User({
                email
            });

            await user.create();

        } catch (err) {
            res.status(500).json({
                msg: 'Что-то пошло не так, попробуйте снова'
            });
        }

        function isEmpty(str) {
            return (!str || 0 === str.length);
        }
    }
);

module.exports = router;
```

```js
app.use('/api/auth', require('./routes/auth.routes'));
```

Как решить проблему?

Comment: так у вас url должна быть `http://localhost:5000/api/auth/login`

Comment: судя по коду, запрос должен быть на http://localhost:5000/api/auth/login. ты же роут объявляешь под префиксом '/api/auth'